# I installed Windows 10 (kb4592438) and get the blue screen of death

Tags: windows-10, bsod

I installed this Windows 10 (kb4592438) and get blue screen of death, the whole PC goes really slow the audio will slow down and the mouse will move and then just stop and freeze and after 10 seconds it blue screen of death.

I did an in-place install and went back to Windows 10 (20h2) it was fine until I install this Windows 10 (kb4592438) update again and it just blue screen of deaths after a while, I have uninstalled the update and haven't had a blue screen of death in a few hours.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser!  This is a Q&A site--so that means you need to ask a question, and I'm not seeing one here.  If the system works with the KB uninstalled, leave it uninstalled.  It's not the first time a WIndows Update has had issues.

Comment: KB4592438 is the Dec 2020 cumulative update. There may be an issue between it and your machine. If the update stays uninstalled, leave it to the January 2021 cumulative update.

Comment: I am having a similar problem on a Lenovo G510 machine. Fresh install of Windows 10 from Microsoft website. While installing this update the computer freezes. Reproduced the problem several times.

Comment: It seems this update caused network  problems at my side. Since 2 days my network did not work after power up.  Disabling and enabling the interface solved it. 
When checking the update history, I noticed KB4592438 installed around that period. Uninstalled it and the problem was gone.

Answer (score 0):

Same here...random problem under heavy load to memory managment twice a day.
Checked memory : good.
So I uninstalled KB4592438 (wusa /uninstall /kb:4592438) and I'm back in the game...never had new bsod since then. Also stopped updates.

Suspect DMA driver not properly working with this cumulative KB.

VIII

Comment: This might be true. What I was doing was this: Fresh install of Windows 10 H2, connected to internet and updates were starting. This KB was getting installed before some drivers and was causing the computer to freeze. The solution I found was: Fresh install, DO NOT CONNECT TO INTERNET, manually install all drivers from Lenovo's page then connected to the internet. The update installed successfully without any freezes. So yes, this was driver related in my case. Hope this post will be useful for someone.